# Nativescript - Error: Type AppRoutingModule does not have 'ngModuleDef' property

Tags: nativescript-angular

I want to get my hands on Nativescript + Angular using quick preview but I am getting an error while running the *tns preview* command. I don't want to go through the full setup of nativescript. I am Angular v11 installed on my machine.

> Error: Type AppRoutingModule does not have 'ngModuleDef' property.
> at com.tns.Runtime.runModule(Native Method)
> at com.tns.Runtime.runModule(Runtime.java:674)
> at com.tns.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:666)
> at com.tns.NativeScriptApplication.onCreate(NativeScriptApplication.java:21)
> at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1165)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6039)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:207)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1748)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6863)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)

Is there any workaround to launch the preview without downgrading angular version?

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { Routes } from "@angular/router";
import { NativeScriptRouterModule } from "@nativescript/angular";

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: "", redirectTo: "/home", pathMatch: "full" },
    { path: "home", loadChildren: () => import("~/app/home/home.module").then((m) => m.HomeModule) },
    { path: "browse", loadChildren: () => import("~/app/browse/browse.module").then((m) => m.BrowseModule) },
    { path: "search", loadChildren: () => import("~/app/search/search.module").then((m) => m.SearchModule) },
    { path: "featured", loadChildren: () => import("~/app/featured/featured.module").then((m) => m.FeaturedModule) },
    { path: "settings", loadChildren: () => import("~/app/settings/settings.module").then((m) => m.SettingsModule) }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [NativeScriptRouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [NativeScriptRouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: can you send AppRoutingModule.ts and AppRoutingModule.tns.ts file too

Comment: @miladfm I have added AppRoutingModule.ts. Just FYI - I haven't made any changes to this file yet.

Comment: 1- is it a shared project (web and mobile) or just a mobile application? 2- can share us appModule and package json too

Comment: I don't think it  would be helpful as I haven't added any extra lines of code in any of these files.